# How to used a tensor in different graphs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph

I build two graphs in my code, graph1 and graph2.

There is a tensor, named `embedding`, in graph1. I tied to use it in graph2 by using get_variable, while the error is `tensor must be from the same graph as Tensor`. I found that this error occurs because they are in different graphs.

So how can I use a tensor in graph1 to graph2?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't

Comment: No, you cannot do that. Your options are either have both models in the same graph object or manually read the value of the variable in one graph and [`load`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#load) it into a similar variable in the other graph.

Answer (score 0):

expanding on @jdehesa's comment,

embedding could be trained initially, saved from graph1 and restored to graph2 using tensorflows saver/restore tools. for this to work you should assign embedding to a name/variable scope in graph1 and reuse the scope in graph2